# Tracking a none ascii domain with google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a website hosted somewhere. There are about 20 domains for this website.
Until now I have setup a cross-domain, subdomain & iframe Google Analytics Tracking code which works fine.

My problem is that there is one domain with a none ascii character (ä) which is not tracked.

My Trackingcode:

```
var hostname = 'someDomäin.com'; //Depends on domain which is used

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', hostname]);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Google Analytics is tracking all domains correctly except of those witch special characters (ä,ö,ü).

How can I manage that Analytics is tracking every domain correctly?

Sorry for my bad english, I'm from Germany.

Comment: What character encoding is your page using?

Comment: UTF-8. Document is saved in UTF-8, Charset is set to UTF-8 in meta tag. Usage of e.g 'ä' works in the pages content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Google Analytics works correctly with international characters.

To get this to work you would need to use Punycode as the domain name.

Here's a handy [Converter](http://mct.verisign-grs.com/convertServlet?input=someDom%C3%A4in.com)